# Gmail account is being used by someone to log in to Facebook

Tags: gmail, facebook

Someone with the same name as mine has created an account on Facebook with my Gmail ID. All her Facebook notifications are delivered to my Gmail account. I tried changing the settings on her Facebook page, but I guess she changes that. Does that mean she's also getting the same notifications? But I have no problem logging into my Gmail account with my username and password.

Is this person also able to access Gmail with the same username?

Answer (score 3):

If she cannot log into your Gmail account, eventually Facebook is going to send a message to your Gmail account asking her for verification.  Just let the verification emails sit without clicking on the link, and her Facebook account will eventually be removed.

From https://www.facebook.com/help/www/121102861305251

> I received an email that I created a new Facebook account, but I didn’t sign up for a new account.
>
> Most likely, someone tried to sign up for a Facebook account using your email address by mistake. The sign-up process isn't finished until someone clicks the link in this email, so the easiest thing to do is ignore the email. You can also:
>
> - Click the link at the bottom of the email to let us know this wasn't you
> - Add this email address to your account, if you have a Facebook account
> - File a report

You must be logged into Facebook under your own account to access the help page.

If she can access your Gmail account, change the password as soon as possible and go through the steps above with Facebook.